# Search W3Schools with search-URL?

Tags: search, search-engines

It seems that the domain http://www.w3schools.com/ can be searched only if I go to their website and MANUALLY enter the search term into the search field.

Is it possible to search this domain (not with Google site search) but with a specific search URL like for example [http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%25s)

My browser: Chrome

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I search W3Schools?

Add `site:w3schools.com:` at the start of your google search query.

> **Search within a specific site**
>
> Precede your query with `site:` if you know you want your answer from
>   within a specific site or type of site (.org, .edu).
>
> For example: `site:edu` or `site:nytimes.com`.

Source [All Tips & Tricks](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/tipstricks/all.html)

---

#### The W3Schools search should be accessed directly

As far as I know this is not possible as w3schools have not designed their website in the way that you want.

In any case they use google to perform their searching ("powered by Custom Search").

The results are almost identical when performing a direct search via google.

For example (searching for `href`):

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aw3schools.com%3A+href&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 returns "About 2,670 results"

Searching for `href` on http://www.w3schools.com returns "About 2,720 results"

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I wrote: Not with Google site search. The W3Schools search should be accessed directly.

Comment: @user1580348 Answer updated.